# Pandas rolling with a single-sided window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use `pandas.DataFrame.rolling` to achieve the following:

At index `i`, I want the rolling `sum`, `mean`, `median`, ... for the last `size_win` values using a `parzen` window. It is *crucial* to only regard values from the past (i.e. index `<i`) and *not* consider any values from the future (this is a "What information did we have at time `i`?" scenario). The second constraint is: I want a single-sided `parzen` window, i.e. value at index `i` should get maximum weight, `i-1` a smaller weight, `i-2` an even smaller weight, …, `i-size_win` the minimum weight.

Using the standard

`df.rolling(window=size_win, win_type='parzen').sum()`

does not work for me, as it will give index `i` minimum weight and `i-(size_win/2)` the maximum weight. Supplying the `center` argument would give index `i` the maximum weight but also use future `>i` values for the calculation.

I found a solution using `pandas.DataFrame.rolling(...).apply` but that is (of course) incredibly slow.

See the following example:

```
import time

import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

size_win = 1000

def window_single_sided_parzen(window_size):
    return sp.signal.parzen((window_size-1)*2+1)[0:window_size]

def custom_rolling_sum(x, window):
    return (x * window).sum()

t_start = time.time()
df_rolled_fast = df.rolling(window=size_win, win_type='parzen').sum()
print(f'Run time of builtin: {time.time() - t_start:.2f} s')

t_start = time.time()
df_rolled = df.rolling(window=size_win).apply(lambda x: custom_rolling_sum(x, window_single_sided_parzen(size_win)))
print(f'Run time of apply: {time.time() - t_start:.2f} s')
```

The builtin rolling takes 1.3 s in my case (producing not the result I want) and my own solution takes 54 s.

Any ideas how to solve this more efficiently?

Answer (score 3):

Spotted my own error in reasoning:

```
df_rolled = df.rolling(window=size_win).apply(lambda x: custom_rolling_sum(x, window_single_sided_parzen(size_win)))
```

I naively thought, it would call the expensive function `window_single_sided_parzen(size_win)` only once. In fact it is called for every single row. Switching to

```
win = window_single_sided_parzen(size_win)
df_rolled = df.rolling(window=size_win).apply(lambda x: custom_rolling_sum(x, win))
```

is much faster. Not as fast as the builtin functionality, but fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could possibly be terrible...but I have a similar need to you for a single sided historical rolling average.  I wanted to be able to use intrinsic functions in a normal way...I think I accomplished that doing it this way:

```
# %% Import Base Packages
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# end%%

# %% Import other packages to overwrite
from pandas.core import window as rwindow
from pandas.core.dtypes.generic import (ABCSeries,ABCDataFrame)
from pandas.core.dtypes.common import is_integer
# end%%

# %% Overwrite Functions and methods
class Window_single_sided(rwindow.Window):
    def _prep_window(self, **kwargs):
        """
        provide validation for our window type, return the window
        we have already been validated
        """

        window = self._get_window()
        if isinstance(window, (list, tuple, np.ndarray)):
            return _asarray_tuplesafe(window).astype(float)
        elif is_integer(window):
            import scipy.signal as sig

            # the below may pop from kwargs
            def _validate_win_type(win_type, kwargs):
                arg_map = {'kaiser': ['beta'],
                           'gaussian': ['std'],
                           'general_gaussian': ['power', 'width'],
                           'slepian': ['width']}
                if win_type in arg_map:
                    return tuple([win_type] + _pop_args(win_type,
                                                        arg_map[win_type],
                                                        kwargs))
                return win_type

            def _pop_args(win_type, arg_names, kwargs):
                msg = '%s window requires %%s' % win_type
                all_args = []
                for n in arg_names:
                    if n not in kwargs:
                        raise ValueError(msg % n)
                    all_args.append(kwargs.pop(n))
                return all_args

            win_type = _validate_win_type(self.win_type, kwargs)
            # GH #15662. `False` makes symmetric window, rather than periodic.
            #----Only Line I changed to get a single sided window----
            return sig.get_window(win_type, (window-1)*2+1, False).astype(float)[0:window]

def rolling_new(obj, win_type=None, **kwds):
    if not isinstance(obj, (ABCSeries, ABCDataFrame)):
        raise TypeError('invalid type: %s' % type(obj))


    if win_type is not None:

        # ---Updated to use the new single_sided class when appropriate
        if win_type.endswith('_single_sided'):
            return Window_single_sided(obj, win_type=re.sub('\_single_sided$', '',win_type), **kwds)
        #----Had to rwindow prefaces here...
        return rwindow.Window(obj, win_type=win_type, **kwds)

    return rwindow.Rolling(obj, **kwds)

# Here we set this new method instead of the existing one.
rwindow.rolling = rolling_new
# end%%

# %% Here we test it out
df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])

df['triang'] = df[0].rolling(5,win_type='triang').sum()
df['triang_single_sided'] = df[0].rolling(5,win_type='triang_single_sided').sum()
df['boxcar'] = df[0].rolling(5,win_type='boxcar').sum()
ax = df.plot(x=0,y=['triang','triang_single_sided','boxcar'])
ax.set_ylabel('Sum with different Methods')
# end%%

# %% Here we test it out
from scipy.stats import norm
t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi*2,5000)
y = np.sin(t)*10 + norm.rvs(size=5000)

df = pd.DataFrame({'t':t,'y':y})
df
df['triang'] = df['y'].rolling(50,win_type='triang').mean()
df['triang_single_sided'] = df['y'].rolling(50,win_type='triang_single_sided').mean()
df['boxcar'] = df['y'].rolling(50,win_type='boxcar').mean()
ax = df.plot(x=t,y=['y','triang','triang_single_sided','boxcar'])
ax.set_ylabel('Mean with different Methods')
plt.show()
# end%%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `numpy.convolve`. It is fast. You can build whatever window function you want as a kernel, and apply it to your series. To prevent 'future' values from affecting the rolling function, pad your kernel so that half of it contains zeros.

Here is an example computing a weighted moving average:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def wma(arr, period):
    kernel = np.arange(period, 0, -1)
    kernel = np.concatenate([np.zeros(period - 1), kernel / kernel.sum()])
    return np.convolve(arr, kernel, 'same')

df = pd.DataFrame({'value':np.arange(11)})
df['wma'] = wma(df['value'], 4)
```

You can also use `numpy.correlate` if you reverse the kernel.